# How to change delay time for an object in DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a tableView where cells appear with certain delay. Delay depends on how many letters there are in text of each cell. 
So my question is if there is a way that I can change delay time if user does something (e.g. scrolls down tableView).

Ideally I want next cell to appear with no delay at all if tableView is scrolled down.

I guess the answer lays somewhere in `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: task)`. Though I am not sure if it executes just the next queued task or all tasks in the queue. (Apparently I need just the next task). Anyway with the code below my app crashes.

```
var task: DispatchWorkItem?
var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

//Checking if tableView was scrolled.

override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
   if lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        print("Table view scrolled-down!")
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: task!)
   }
   else{
        print("Scrolled up")
   }
}

//Updating my tableView with delay

func updateTableView(nextPassageID: Int) {

    task = DispatchWorkItem {
         self.numberOfCells += 1
         let indexPath = IndexPath(row: nextPassageID, section: 0)
         self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delay, execute: task!)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change delay time for an object in `DispatchQueue`

Bottom line, you don’t. If you want it to start sooner than previously scheduled, just [`cancel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780910-cancel) it and the dispatch a create new one without any delay associated with it.

Alternatively, you can use a [`Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer), which you can schedule but also [`fire`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1414035-fire) before the scheduled fire date occurs, it will run it and then [`invalidate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415405-invalidate) it.

Just be careful of strong reference cycles. For example, in your closures (whether `DispatchWorkItem` or closure-based timer, consider using `[weak self]` capture list, so that the closure doesn’t maintain a strong reference to `self`. Likewise, if you have an ivar to your `DispatchWorkItem` or `Timer`, consider (a) using a local var for the item/timer, (b) add that to your queue/runloop, and then (c) make your ivar a `weak` reference, so that when the item is run and/or the timer fires, that your ivar will be automatically released, avoiding hanging on to references beyond their useful lifespan.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable. Also Timer seems to be a good option. Thank you!